# Mysql pool.query( ) performance slowness

Tags: node.js

I'm following the doc
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 150,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

The next line after this code example says:
This is a shortcut for the pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release() code flow. Using pool.getConnection() is useful to share connection state for subsequent queries. This is because two calls to pool.query() may use two different connections and run in parallel.

i'm confused, don't see the difference. So for better performance for many query requests, i should just call

```
pool.getConnection();
pool.query();
```

don't call connection.release() when there're many query requests ?

Comment: Some db platforms have temporary or session tables that only last as long as the connection is open.  This would be a reason to keep the same connection.  Also there is some "cost" to opening and closing connections.

Comment: I am confused by your conclusion, where does it say you should not call connection.release for performance benefits? (and "don't see the difference" difference between what?)

Comment: yes i do understand the cost to open a connection, but i don't see the difference of 2 cases, my questions is, shall i call connection.release() or not to improve performance ? thx !

Comment: @RolandStarke i'm confused by the doc, so my summary most likely is wrong. i don't see the difference of calling pool.query() or the other way (3 steps pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release()), pool.query includes connection.release, why doc still says "two calls to pool.query() may use two different connections and run in parallel" ?

Comment: The difference between `pool.query();` vs `pool.getConnection() connection.query(); connection.release()`. is that you can call `connection.query()` multiple times. You need it if you use transactions for example, or when the order of your queries is important.

Comment: @RolandStarke now i see, many thx !